# Can I grant a User all the Root permissions

Tags: command-line, permissions, xubuntu, root, 19.04

Can I grant a User all the Root permissions by logging into root account and then log in to that user account and delete the Root user itself by logging into the User to which rights have been granted?

Comment: Root user is disabled by default in Ubuntu.  The user created on installation of Xubuntu (from your tag) is granted `sudo` rights so there is no need for a root login thus is disabled by default on install.  You can make `sudo` work without password, but it's unwise.

Comment: Could you explain _why_ you want to delete the root user? Linux is made to work _with_ it. If you’re worried about having one more user than you actually use, then look into the `/etc/passwd` file – there is a lot of them in fact!

Comment: This seems like an early-semester homework question in a class that does not use Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

This would be effectively renaming `root` to another username. This can be done technically, though not the way you described. But it would be a very bad idea, because a lot of things assume the privileged user is called `root`, and they would break if it isn't. So working with `sudo`, as it's the default in Ubuntu, is probably the best way. That also allows you to use the extended privileges only when necessary, which makes it less likely to break things with a simple typo.

Comment: What things assume that `root` is named `root`? I guess some shell scripts might, but most tools will check that the UID is `0`, not the name of the user as far as I know.

Comment: @terdon Many daemons use `root` as the user name to set up cronjobs, send report mails to, check the permissions of their config directory and the like. As a commenter [next door](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8447/how-do-you-rename-root) wrote, "You're right no application should assume [that the username to uid 0 is `root`]. But I'd really like to recieve 1$ for every application or script that does!"

Comment: Heh, fair enough :)